# Eloquent ORM hasManyTrough

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

i have a hasManyTrough() relation in my database but could not get it to work with eloquent.

the relation in my database

```
category(id)
entry(id)
category_entries(category_id, entry_id)
```

i have 3 models

```
Category
  has_many CategoryEntries

Entry
  has_many CategoryEntries

CategoryEntry
  belongs_to Category
  belongs_to Entry
```

so every category has many entries and every entry has many categories.

in rails i would do the following

```
Entry
  has_many CategoryEntries
  has_many Categories, through: :category_entries
```

i have created the following in eloquent

```
  CategoryEntry
    public function category(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
    }
    public function entry(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Entry');
    }

  Category
    public function categoryEntries(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\CategoryEntry');
    }

  Entry
    public function categoryEntries(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\CategoryEntry');
    }


    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Category', 'App\CategoryEntry', 'category_id', 'id');
    }
```

but this will create the following sql command:

```
select `entries`.*, `category_entries`.`category_id` from `entries` 
inner join `category_entries` on `category_entries`.`id` = `entries`.`entry_id`
```

this makes no sence. where is my mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described in your question, relation is

`Category` (hasMany) `Entry` (hasMany) `CategoryEntries`

So we can add `hasManyThrough` relation in `Category` Model not in `Entry` model

```
class Category
.......

public function categoryEntries()
{
    $this->hasManyThrough(App\CategoryEntry::class, App\Entry::class);
}
```

**UPDATE**

if the relation is based on  db you have given, then you have Many-Many relation between `Category` and `Entry`. then you can have,

```
class Entry
....

public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(App\Category::class, 'category_entries');
}
```

Comment: hm, but both models have a hasMany `CategoryEntry`relation. why i can't get the `Category` for each `Entry` through the `CategoryEntry` model?

Comment: Based on your update are u referring to a pivot table Many-Many relation?. The code part given and relation given is conflicting

Comment: i see. i've made a mistake in my question. i want all `Categories`for my `Entry`. so i build a Many-Many relation with a separate model `CategoryEntry`. or is this a bad way in laravel?

Comment: Many-Many relation `category_entries` act like pivot table, see my updated answer. https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many